# How to get java code to compile in a directory

Tags: java, subdirectory

I have this in a terminal. When I call this from the home directory there is no problems it works perfectly fine. But when I put this into a sub directory CPS3498 and compile it there is no error. When I try to do `java home/student/pshivam/CPS3498/encrypt` to run the program it gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /home/student/pshivam/CPS3498/encrypt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .home.student.pshivam.CPS3498.encrypt
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: /home/student/pshivam/CPS3498/encrypt.  Program will exit
```

Code as follows.

```
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class encrypt {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            try {
                File file = new File("/home/student/pshivam/CPS3498/letter.txt");
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(line);
                    stringBuffer.append("\n");
                }
                fileReader.close();
                for(int i = 0; i<stringBuffer.length(); i++){
                    int encrypt = 0;
                    encrypt = (int)stringBuffer.charAt(i);
                    encrypt = encrypt * 9;
                    stringBuffer.setCharAt(i, (char)encrypt);
                    File message = new File("/home/student/pshivam/CPS3498/secret.txt");
                    try
                    {
                        message.createNewFile();
                        FileWriter msgFile = new FileWriter(message);
                        BufferedWriter msgBuff = new BufferedWriter(msgFile);
                        msgBuff.write(stringBuffer.toString());
                        msgBuff.close();
                    } 
                    finally 
                    {

                    }
                }

            } finally{

            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this source file have a packaage?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I dont have a package

Comment: I have another code that is similar to this but just decrypts

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a package specified for the `encrypt` class, then you should be able to run it from *any* directory using `java encrypt` from the directory where the `.class` file is located.

If you had specified the following package:

```
package home.student.pshivam.CPS3498
```

then you would build from the *root* directory above `home` (presumably `\` if you are using Linux).  You would then run the program *again* from the root directory using

```
java home.student.pshivam.CPS3498.encrypt
```

By the way, naming convention in Java is that class names should begin with a captial letter, i.e. use `Encrypt` rather than `encrypt`.